# for some reason query is returning all but 2 records even though it technically meets the criteria

Tags: sql, sql-server

I found something odd in one of my apps today - actually someone pointed it out to me. I have a table with a whole bunch of clients, and let the user run a report to find potential duplicates. This is a preliminary duplicate search so I go by the first few characters of first and last name.

Let's imagine i have this list of clients:

```
tblA
ClientID        FName         LName
1               Carol         Villa
2               Carol         Villa
3               Gainy         Brimes
4               Gainy         Brimes
```

And this is the query I'm using:

```
 select ClientID, FName, LName 
 from (select t.*,  count(*) over (partition by (substring(FName,0,4)), (substring(LName,0,4)), dob) as cnt  from tblClients t   ) t  
 where cnt > 1  
 order by  FName, LName
```

If I run this query against this table I only get these records:

```
ClientID      FName        LName
1             Carol        Villa
2             Carol        Villa
```

It is not showing me Gainy Brimes, any reason why?

Comment: What is your dbms? If it's sql server, `substring` is not 0 based like C#, but 1. In other words, `substring(FName,0,4)` is the same as `substring(FName,1,3)`. This doesn't explain your issue though.

Comment: Where is your `dob` column in sample data ?

Comment: SSMS 2012 @HoneyBadger

Comment: @YogeshSharma that's why! The DOB does not match for both clients which is why it isn't getting pulled up.

Comment: You should get all four records from that query.

Comment: yes in my case the DOB is not matching which is why the records aren't getting pulled. Sorry for waiting your time fellas, my mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer has already been discovered by Koosh himself.
Since DOB is used in the partition of the window function, an unmatching DOB could ignore some of the "suspected" duplicates.

But here's a little test script to demonstrate that effect:

```
declare @tblClients table (ClientID int, FName varchar(30), LName varchar(30), dob int);
insert into @tblClients (ClientID, FName, LName, dob) values
 (1,'Carol','Villa',100)
,(2,'Carina','Vilpo',100)
,(3,'Garcy','Brimes',100)
,(4,'Garry','Bricks',200)
;

select ClientID, FName, LName
, dob, cnt, rn
, CASE WHEN cnt > 1 THEN 'Has Partial Dups' ELSE 'No Partials Dups' END as ThereBeDups
from 
(
 select ClientID, FName, LName, dob,  
 count(*) over (partition by dob, substring(FName,1,3), substring(LName,1,3)) as cnt,
 row_number() over (partition by dob, substring(FName,1,3), substring(LName,1,2) order by ClientID desc) as rn
 from @tblClients
) t
--where cnt > 1
order by  FName, LName;
```

**Result:**

```
ClientID    FName   LName   dob cnt rn  ThereBeDups
--------    -----   -----   --- --- --  ----------------
2           Carina  Vilpo   100 2   1   Has Partial Dups
1           Carol   Villa   100 2   2   Has Partial Dups
3           Garcy   Brimes  100 1   1   No Partial Dups
4           Garry   Bricks  200 1   1   No Partial Dups
```